# Error: Debug Failure. False expression: Non-string value passed to `ts.resolveTypeReferenceDirective`,

Tags: javascript, typescript, inquirer, inquirerjs

I don't know why am I getting the following error which say:

```bash
Error: Debug Failure. False expression: Non-string value passed to `ts.resolveTypeReferenceDirective`, likely by a wrapping package working with an outdated `resolveTypeReferenceDirectives` signature. This is probably not a problem in TS itself.
```

When i try to import the package `inquirer` in my nodejs application.

```bash
console.log("Hello world!");
import inquirer from "inquirer";
....
```

To run the application I'm using `ts-node` and I'm running it as follows:

```bash
ts-node index.ts
```

This is my `package.json` file:

```json
{
....
     "dependencies": {
    "chalk": "^4.1.2",
    "cors": "^2.8.5",
    "cross-fetch": "2.6.1",
    "dotenv": "^16.0.1",
    "inquirer": "^8.2.4",
    "ts-node": "^10.8.1",
    "typescript": "^4.7.3"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/chalk": "^2.2.0",
    "@types/cors": "^2.8.12",
    "@types/inquirer": "^8.2.1",
    "@types/node": "^17.0.42",
    "nodemon": "^2.0.16",
    "ts-node-dev": "^2.0.0"
  }
....
}
```

- I've tried to change the versions of `inquirer` and `typescript` but still it did not work.

What can be possibly the problem.

Answer (score 1):

I have met with the same error but in my case I had no `ts-node` dependency installed, I fixed the error by adding that dependency.

You can also try to run your application with `npx`, in your case that will be  `npx ts-node index.ts`.